# Get distinct number of members

Tags: mysql, sql

Perhaps Im being stupid here but consider this table

[image]

I want to get how many **unique members** are registered so I use this Query

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT member_nr, count(member_nr) as nr FROM Multiple_Orders 
                Where order = '$pTour' AND  round ='$pRound'";
```

**My Problem**

*The result is returning 6*

Sure there are 6 members in the column but ***I want to get the number of unique members which should be 2***, that is why I am using `Distinct`

What am I missing here

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question? Where are you splitting a string? There's no name or lastname in the question.

Comment: I agree with Barmar. Tags `php` and `mysqli` are not necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is how you use `DISTINCT`

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT(member_nr) as nr FROM Multiple_Orders 
                Where order = '$pTour' AND  round ='$pRound'";
```

which will give you a list of unique members

and this is how you count how many unique members you have

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(member_nr)) as nr FROM Multiple_Orders 
                Where order = '$pTour' AND  round ='$pRound'";
```

which will give you the number of unique members

Answer (score 2):

Use query to get count of distinct member:

```
 $sql="SELECT count(distinct(member_nr)) as nr FROM Multiple_Orders 
                    Where order = '$pTour' AND  round ='$pRound' group by member_nr";
```

Use query to get distinct member:

```
 $sql="SELECT distinct(member_nr) as nr FROM Multiple_Orders 
                    Where order = '$pTour' AND  round ='$pRound' group by member_nr";
```

Add **group by** clause to get unique members and count of each member:

```
$sql="SELECT member_nr, count(member_nr) as nr FROM Multiple_Orders 
                Where order = '$pTour' AND  round ='$pRound' group by member_nr";
```

Comment: He wants the number of distinct member numbers, not the count of each of them.

Comment: he uses count also in the query to get the unique members and their count i think

Comment: He does that because he doesn't know the right way to do it.